# how to delete item in Internal Storage

Tags: android, android-listview

hello everyone ive created a class that save file in Internal Storage and display it on ListView. but my problem is to HOW TO DELETE on of the item? here's my code

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String fileName = edFileName.getText().toString();
                String content = edContent.getText().toString();

                FileOutputStream fos;
                try {
                    fos = openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    fos.write(content.getBytes());
                    fos.close();

                    Toast.makeText(
                            addThis.this, 
                            fileName + " saved", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                ShowSavedFiles();

            }});
}
 void ShowSavedFiles(){
        SavedFiles = getApplicationContext().fileList();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter
        = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                SavedFiles);

        listSavedFiles.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably create and register ( `registerForContextMenu(MyListView)` ) a contextmenu in your activity for your ListView and implement the deletion there.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu); //your xml menu 
    return true;
}

@Override
 public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
 super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

     menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Delete");
 }

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

       if(item.getTitle().equals("Delete")){
         TextView tv = (TextView)((RelativeLayout) ((AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo()).targetView).getChildAt(0);
      //tv.getText(); will probably hold your filename
      //and just use the deleteFile() operations to remove it from the internal storage
       .............
       }
```

---

**Read this about how to work with internal storage**
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

hope it helps abit

Answer (score 1):

You can delete files from Internal by using `getFilesDir().listFiles()` which will return you Array of Files that are present in your Files Folder.

```
File[] files = getFilesDir().listFiles();

for (File file : files) {
    file.delete();
}
```

If you want to delete a `particular` file you can get the `name` of the `file`, `compare` and `delete` it.

```
if(file.getName().equals("xyz.extension"))
  file.delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

I did had the same problem in my multichoicemodelistener. 
It took me a while to multi delete my files in my listview(saved in internal storage)

But here is my code for deleting internal storage files in multichoicemodelistener

```
 public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {         
       case R.id.list_context_delte:
                nr = 0;

                SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray = getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();

                for(int i = sparseBooleanArray.size() -1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    if (sparseBooleanArray.get(i)) {
                   RowItem selecteditem = mAdapter.getItem(sparseBooleanArray.keyAt(i));
                   String selecteditemString = selecteditem.getFilename().toString();

                    File dir = getFilesDir();
                    File file = new File(dir, (selecteditemString));
                    file.delete();
                    mAdapter.remove(selecteditem);
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



                    }
                }
                    mode.finish();


        }



        return false;

    }
```